# Firebase Analytics Can't Find All Projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

The majority of projects have gone missing from Firebase console. Selecting a project and then on the top-left dropdown, selecting 'See All Projects' takes you to a screen with just a few projects. How do I see all the projects?

Comment: That sounds odd. I'd try it on a different browser, or on a browser with all plugins/extensions disabled. If that doesn't solve the problem, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it on a different browser and on a browser with all plugins/extensions disabled but that didn't resolve. Have reached out to Firebase support and awaiting feedback...